# Java : unescape XML attribute value

Tags: java, xml

I've some XML attribute value that I need to unescape to get their actual value; I know about `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXML()` - but does it work for XML attribute ?

Comment: Are you manually parsing XML instead of using a library, i.e. why do you need to unescape an attribute value? How did it get escaped?

Comment: I receive somehow those 'raw' value from external code I cannot change.

Comment: Have you at least tested it? You know stackoverflow is not a testing tool :)

Comment: How does the value look? Please post a sample XML snippet. Also, please post the code that receives and parses the XML.

Comment: It should work. But if you read the commons-lang documentation, you will see that `unescapeXML` supports only the five basic XML entities (gt, lt, quot, amp, apos). It does not support DTDs or external entities. So it entirely depends on the kind of data you have.

Comment: Why do you need to unescape the value: an XML parser will do this for you automatically. Is it perhaps that you aren't using an XML parser?